# inconsistent authentication results when trying to git clone TFS to linux

Tags: linux, git, tfs

I have the strangest thing - I have 2 linux servers:

1. Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9
2. CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

both have git version 2.14.1. both are trying to clone git hosted on TFS server (TFS2017). they both issue an error:

```
error: unable to read askpass response from '/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass'
```

but afterwards they both prompt a username and password for the TFS server. after entering the user and password only the first (red hat) is managed to clone. the centos failes on

```
fatal: Authentication failed for URL...
```

any ideas ???

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using?  Basic, NTLM or Kerberos?

Comment: according to IT we are using Kerberos and PAM (plug-able authentication module).

Comment: That makes sense.  My suspicion is that the version of curl included with CentOS does not have Kerberos / GSSAPI support (but RHEL does).